# TypeError: crypto__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.scryptSync is not a function in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, encryption, cryptography, frontend

I'm encountering an issue with my React  js code that involves the **`crypto`** library. I'm trying to use the **`crypto.scryptSync`** function, but I'm getting the following error:

```
crypto__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_\_.scryptSync is not a function

TypeError: crypto__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_\_.scryptSync is not a function
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error, and I could use some guidance on how to resolve it. Here's the relevant code:

```
export function decryptKey(encrypted, pepper, salt) {
  const iv = Buffer.from(encrypted.slice(0, 32), "hex");
  const key = crypto.scryptSync(pepper, salt, 32);
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);

  let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted.slice(32), "hex", "utf8");
  decrypted += decipher.final("utf8");

  return decrypted;
}
```

I have thoroughly searched both Stack Overflow and Google, but I could only find solutions that are specifically tailored for Node.js and Electron.js.

Answer (score -1):

The crypto module you are trying to use is typically available in Node.js environments, but when working with React.js, which runs in a web browser, the crypto module is not directly available because it is a Node.js built-in module.

To perform cryptographic operations in a web browser, you should use the Web Crypto API, which is a JavaScript API designed for secure cryptographic operations in web applications. The Web Crypto API is supported in modern web browsers, but it's not available natively in React.js itself. You can use it directly in your React.js application code.

Here's an example of how you can rewrite your decryptKey function using the Web Crypto API:

```
export async function decryptKey(encrypted, pepper, salt) {
  // Convert hexadecimal strings to ArrayBuffer
  const iv = hexStringToArrayBuffer(encrypted.slice(0, 32));
  const data = hexStringToArrayBuffer(encrypted.slice(32));

  // Import the password (pepper) as a CryptoKey
  const passwordKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'raw',
    stringToArrayBuffer(pepper),
    { name: 'PBKDF2' },
    false,
    ['deriveBits']
  );

  // Derive the encryption key using PBKDF2
  const encryptionKey = await crypto.subtle.deriveBits(
    {
      name: 'PBKDF2',
      salt: stringToArrayBuffer(salt),
      iterations: 100000, // You can adjust the number of iterations
      hash: 'SHA-256',
    },
    passwordKey,
    256 // Key length in bits (AES-256)
  );

  // Decrypt the data using AES-CBC
  const decryptedData = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
    {
      name: 'AES-CBC',
      iv,
    },
    encryptionKey,
    data
  );

  // Convert the decrypted ArrayBuffer to a UTF-8 string
  const decrypted = new TextDecoder().decode(decryptedData);

  return decrypted;
}

function hexStringToArrayBuffer(hexString) {
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(hexString.length / 2);
  for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = parseInt(hexString.substr(i * 2, 2), 16);
  }
  return bytes;
}

function stringToArrayBuffer(str) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  return encoder.encode(str);
}
```

Refrence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto